# CSS para a resolução do Google Pixel 3 XL

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Qual seria a media querie para a resolução do novo celular: **Google Pixel 3 XL** ?

[**Neste link**](https://vizdevices.yesviz.com/devices/google-pixel-2xl/) eu tenho as media queries para a versão 2:

```
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 384dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 3dppx) { 
    /* Retina styles here */
}
```

Eu desconfio que seja assim, mas eu não tenho nenhuma base para me certificar:

```
/** Google Pixel 3 XL  **/
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 740px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 523dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 4dppx) {
  /*** exemplo ***/
}
```

Comment: Como comentei abaixo, da uma olhada aqui que vai te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360441/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-css-resolution-e-pixel-resolution/360460#360460

Answer (score 2):

## O que você procure é

**Google Pixel 3 XL**

Pixel Size   *1440 x 2960*
Viewport     *412 x 847*

[Fonte](https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/)

## Uma tabela para te ajudar no futuro

**Google Pixel 2 XL**

```
1440 x 2880 pixels, 18:9 ratio (~538 ppi density)
```

[Fonte](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_2_xl-8720.php)

**Google Pixel 3 lite**

[Fonte](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3_lite-9408.php)

```
1080 x 2160 pixels, 18:9 ratio (~434 ppi density)
```

**Google Pixel 3**

[Fonte](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3-9256.php)

```
1080 x 2160 pixels, 18:9 ratio (~443 ppi density)
```

**Google Pixel 3 XL**

```
1440 x 2960 pixels, 18.5:9 ratio (~523 ppi density)
```

[Fonte](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3_xl-9257.php)

**Pixel Size    - Viewport**

```
  1440 x 2560   412 x 732
  1080 x 1920   412 x 732
> 1440 x 2960   412 x 847
  1080 x 2160   412 x 824
> 1440 x 2960   360 x 740
  1440 x 2560   480 x 853
  1080 x 1920   480 x 853
  1440 x 2560   360 x 640
  1536 x 2048   768 x 1024
  1200 x 1920   600 x 960
  800 x 1280    800 x 1280
  2560 x 1700   1280 x 850
```

Comment: E como escrevo isso em media queries?

Comment: `only screen and (device-width: 412px) and (device-height: 847px)  
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 18.5/9) 
and (min-resolution: 523dpi)`  ?

Comment: pelo que sei: ppi e dpi são equivalentes, pelo que sei, são equivalentes: [calculo](http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/dpippi.php)

Comment: @IvanFerrer recomendo a leitura ;) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360441/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-css-resolution-e-pixel-resolution/360460#360460