# Resolução máxima ideal para exibir conteúdo em modo mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout-responsivo, resolução-de-tela

Pegando como exemplo o [sistema de grid do Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) cujas classes tratam o conteúdo com *breakpoints* específicos de acordo com a resolução da largura da tela do dispositivo (considerando o *viewport* como *container*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Existe uma resolução máxima ideal recomendada (ou qual a resolução máxima recomendada) para tratar o conteúdo da página em formato mobile (colapsar menu, dispor elementos mais largos um abaixo do outro etc.) de modo que haja uma melhor relação *experiência de usuário/dispositivo usado*?

Ou seja, até `X pixels` de largura da tela, é mais recomendado dispor o conteúdo  em *modo mobile*, levando em consideração uma melhor visualização (tamanho das imagens e texto) em dispositivos móveis (tablets e smartphones) ou mesmo desktops com monitores de baixa resolução (ex., netbooks, monitores pequenos). Considerando também smartphones e tablets de alta-resolução. Isso porque se a página for exibida em *modo desktop* em um smartphone de resolução mais alta, os elementos podem ficar muito pequenos na tela, prejudicando a visualização.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Acho que não tem uma resposta única para sua pergunta. Boa parte dela pode ser tratada com essa outra pergunta [Qual a diferença entre "Css resolution" e "Pixel resolution"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360441/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-css-resolution-e-pixel-resolution) onde vc pode ver melhor como é a diferença de telas de alta e baixa densidade e de como podemos tratar o CSS usando regras de media queries como

```
@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... } /* regra css para telas com 2x a densidade de  pixel */
@media (min-resolution: 3dppx) { ... } /* regra css para telas com 3x a densidade de pixel */
```

Outra parte da resposta pode estar baseada em conceitos tipográficos e de UX, onde algumas boas práticas pode ser seguidas. Como não tem linhas de texto muito longas, por exemplo uma linha de texto com mais de 14 palavras, ou um inputs muito largo, mas que o usuário vai inserir apenas alguns pouco caracteres.

O ideal é que se tenha até 14 palavras por linha. Mas como vc vai tratar isso em um monitor que tem 2.500px de largura? Provavelmente vc vai precisar "partir" o texto em 2 colunas ou mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro ponto é que normalmente no desktop se está perto da tela, no mobile mais perto ainda então o `font-size` não precisa ser tão grande. Já em uma tela de apresentação ou TV vc já está bem longe e o `font-size` precisa ser tratado, independente da resolução da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre as imagens o ideal é que use o `SRCSET` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

```
<img srcset="imagem-320w.jpg 320w,
             imagem-480w.jpg 480w,
             imaem-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="imagem-800w.jpg" alt="">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Para o Bootstrap seria algo como isso**

1 - Se vc estiver usando Bootstrap com o Grid padrão vc teoricamente precisaria das imagens nessas resoluções. Aqui tem a documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200px
);
```

2 - Para carregar as imagens com cada uma das resoluções do grid ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 576px)" srcset="suaimagem-sm.png"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="suaimagem-md.png"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="suaimagem-lg.png"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="suaimagem-lx.png"/>
    <img src="suaimagem-md.png" alt="">
<picture>
```

---

Outra opção seria vc ter uma folha de estilo para mobile.css e uma para desktop.css, e identificando o tipo de dispositivo de acesso por JS vc usa uma folha ou outra. Uma opção tb é usar direto pelo atributo `media` do `link` do css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 769px)" />
```

Mas isso nessa técnica se o dispositivo for mobile, mas tiver mais de `768px` de largura, o usuário vai acabar carregando a folha `desktop.css` mesmo estando no celular... Etão uma abordagem reconhecendo o `user-agent` do dispositivo pelo JS seja melhor.

Uma coisa que pode ajudar é tentar fazer `Media Queries` que peguem a orientação do dispositivo se é `portrait` ou `landscape`.

E o Seu `@media` ficaria algo como isso por exemplo:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }

@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Vc pode ler mais sobre CSS e a orientação do dispositivo aqui:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries#orientation

---

> ### Ponto de Quebra

Sobre os "**Breaking Points**" (pontos de quebra do layout) nem o **Google** ou a **Mozilla** fazem referencias a isso em suas documentações. Na verdade o que eles recomendam e o usa da `Meta Viewport` e tratar o layout de forma que seja responsivo e acessível.

***Seguem links oficiais com as boas praticas.***

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

Também não exite muito consenso entre os *FrameWorks* de Design System mais famosos como **Bootstrap**, **Materialize** e **Foundation**!

Repare abaixo que cada um deles determina uma largura diferente para os `Breaking Points` do `Grid` que usam.

**Bootstrap3** *Breaking Points*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Bootstrap4** *Breaking Points*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Materialize** *Breaking Points*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Foundation** *Breaking Points*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

E para finalizar aqui vai um excelente artigo sobre os tamanhos de tela mais usados atualmente, os dados são de Dezembro de 2017. Artigo: https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/best-screen-size/

**Telas Desktop**

- 1366×768 – 29.25%
- 1920×1080 – 17.34%
- 1440×900 – 7.32%
- 1600×900 – 5.72%
- 1280×800 – 5.27%
- 1280×1024 – 4.51%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Telas Mobile**

- 360×640 – 41.11%
- 375×667 – 9.58%
- 720×1280 – 5.16%
- 320×568 – 4.55%
- 414×736 – 3.79%
- 320×534 – 3.46%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Telas Tabler**

- 768×1024 – 57.99%
- 1280×800 – 5.89%
- 600×1024 – 4.6%
- 601×962 – 3.02%
- 800×1280 – 2.94%
- 1024×600 – 2.36%

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fonte:** http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/tablet/worldwide

> **OBS**: Sempre considere o seu público alvo e a experiencia do usuário antes de começar o desenvolvimento!

*Não sei se toquei em todos os pontos, mas acredito que tenha algo para te dar uma luz.*