# Como manipular imagens? HTML5/CSS3/PHP/JS

Tags: php, html5, css3, imagem, carousel

Estou desenvolvendo um web site para uma imobiliária e exibimos fotos de vários imóveis com `carousel` e outras exibições, porém o site está pesado por causa das fotos e eu não sei qual a melhor forma de deixar com boa qualidade e não tão pesada. qual formato eu deveria utilizar? qual dimensão? devo usar miniaturas para a exibição inicial? Devo usar um script para redimensionamento?

Comment: Isso vai te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386448/resolu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-m%c3%a1xima-ideal-para-exibir-conte%c3%bado-em-modo-mobile

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jpg (JPEG)
São menores e tem uma boa qualidade. Para ícones, use o tamanho correto e não redimensione pelo código pois se feito isto, ele carregará a foto com o tamanho original!

Você pode usar o Photoshop para isso ou esse site:
https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

Outra maneira de fazer isso responder ainda mais rápido é hospedar as imagens em um site. como por exemplo o https://imgur.com/

Combine as imagens redimensionadas em jpeg + hospedada no imgur ou outro site e terá mais fluidez!

Comment: O formato png, vc sabe me dizer como ele se comporta nesse exemplo que me deu? Se eu hospeda-la em um site não seria mais lento o carregamento da mesma no meu site? Já deixo meu agradecimento pela atenção. Grato

Comment: O PNG possui mais qualidade porém é mais pesado em mb do que o JPEG. Quando você deixa no seu servidor essas imagens, vai depender mais da sua velocidade de upload pra enviar essas informações. Ja quando vc deixa em um servidor de imagens, elas carregam mais rapido devido a velocidade desses servidores serem mais rápidas.

Comment: Muito agradecido meu querido. Tenha um ótimo dia.