# Tabela Responsiva mantendo largura e altura das céluas

Tags: html, table, layout-responsivo

Como posso melhorar essa formatação de forma que essa tabela seja bem representado em uma tela de celular? É possível ajustar o código de forma que caso a largura da página seja diminuída, sejam criadas nova linhas com quebras de conteúdo automáticas?

```html
<div class="d-flex">
 <table align="center" class="table table-sm table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered ms">
 <thead>
<tr>titulo</tr>
 </thead><tr class="d-flex ms" align="center">
   <td id=d1 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b1" name="b1" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('1');">
 <span id="s1" class="" > 01</span></button> </td>   <td id=d2 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b2" name="b2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('2');">
 <span id="s2" class="" > 02</span></button> </td>   <td id=d3 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b3" name="b3" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('3');">
 <span id="s3" class="" > 03</span></button> </td>   <td id=d4 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b4" name="b4" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('4');">
 <span id="s4" class="" > 04</span></button> </td>   <td id=d5 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b5" name="b5" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('5');">
 <span id="s5" class="" > 05</span></button> </td>   <td id=d6 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b6" name="b6" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('6');">
 <span id="s6" class="" > 06</span></button> </td>   <td id=d7 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b7" name="b7" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('7');">
 <span id="s7" class="" > 07</span></button> </td>   <td id=d8 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b8" name="b8" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('8');">
 <span id="s8" class="" > 08</span></button> </td>   <td id=d9 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b9" name="b9" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('9');">
 <span id="s9" class="" > 09</span></button> </td>   <td id=d10 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b10" name="b10" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('10');">
 <span id="s10" class="" > 10</span></button> </td> </tr><tr class="d-flex" align="center">  <td id=d11 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b11" name="b11" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('11');">
 <span id="s11" class="" > 11</span></button> </td>   <td id=d12 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b12" name="b12" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('12');">
 <span id="s12" class="" > 12</span></button> </td>   <td id=d13 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b13" name="b13" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('13');">
 <span id="s13" class="" > 13</span></button> </td>   <td id=d14 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b14" name="b14" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('14');">
 <span id="s14" class="" > 14</span></button> </td>   <td id=d15 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b15" name="b15" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('15');">
 <span id="s15" class="" > 15</span></button> </td>   <td id=d16 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b16" name="b16" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('16');">
 <span id="s16" class="" > 16</span></button> </td>   <td id=d17 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b17" name="b17" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('17');">
 <span id="s17" class="" > 17</span></button> </td>   <td id=d18 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b18" name="b18" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('18');">
 <span id="s18" class="" > 18</span></button> </td>   <td id=d19 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b19" name="b19" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('19');">
 <span id="s19" class="" > 19</span></button> </td>   <td id=d20 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b20" name="b20" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('20');">
 <span id="s20" class="" > 20</span></button> </td> </tr><tr class="d-flex" align="center">  <td id=d21 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b21" name="b21" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('21');">
 <span id="s21" class="" > 21</span></button> </td>   <td id=d22 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b22" name="b22" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('22');">
 <span id="s22" class="" > 22</span></button> </td>   <td id=d23 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b23" name="b23" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('23');">
 <span id="s23" class="" > 23</span></button> </td>   <td id=d24 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b24" name="b24" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('24');">
 <span id="s24" class="" > 24</span></button> </td>   <td id=d25 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b25" name="b25" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('25');">
 <span id="s25" class="" > 25</span></button> </td>   <td id=d26 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b26" name="b26" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('26');">
 <span id="s26" class="" > 26</span></button> </td>   <td id=d27 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b27" name="b27" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('27');">
 <span id="s27" class="" > 27</span></button> </td>   <td id=d28 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b28" name="b28" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('28');">
 <span id="s28" class="" > 28</span></button> </td>   <td id=d29 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b29" name="b29" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('29');">
 <span id="s29" class="" > 29</span></button> </td>   <td id=d30 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b30" name="b30" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('30');">
 <span id="s30" class="" > 30</span></button> </td> </tr><tr class="d-flex" align="center">  <td id=d31 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b31" name="b31" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('31');">
 <span id="s31" class="" > 31</span></button> </td>   <td id=d32 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b32" name="b32" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('32');">
 <span id="s32" class="" > 32</span></button> </td>   <td id=d33 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b33" name="b33" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('33');">
 <span id="s33" class="" > 33</span></button> </td>   <td id=d34 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b34" name="b34" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('34');">
 <span id="s34" class="" > 34</span></button> </td>   <td id=d35 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b35" name="b35" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('35');">
 <span id="s35" class="" > 35</span></button> </td>   <td id=d36 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b36" name="b36" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('36');">
 <span id="s36" class="" > 36</span></button> </td>   <td id=d37 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b37" name="b37" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('37');">
 <span id="s37" class="" > 37</span></button> </td>   <td id=d38 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b38" name="b38" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('38');">
 <span id="s38" class="" > 38</span></button> </td>   <td id=d39 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b39" name="b39" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('39');">
 <span id="s39" class="" > 39</span></button> </td>   <td id=d40 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b40" name="b40" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('40');">
 <span id="s40" class="" > 40</span></button> </td> </tr><tr class="d-flex" align="center">  <td id=d41 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b41" name="b41" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('41');">
 <span id="s41" class="" > 41</span></button> </td>   <td id=d42 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b42" name="b42" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('42');">
 <span id="s42" class="" > 42</span></button> </td>   <td id=d43 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b43" name="b43" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('43');">
 <span id="s43" class="" > 43</span></button> </td>   <td id=d44 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b44" name="b44" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('44');">
 <span id="s44" class="" > 44</span></button> </td>   <td id=d45 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b45" name="b45" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('45');">
 <span id="s45" class="" > 45</span></button> </td>   <td id=d46 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b46" name="b46" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('46');">
 <span id="s46" class="" > 46</span></button> </td>   <td id=d47 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b47" name="b47" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('47');">
 <span id="s47" class="" > 47</span></button> </td>   <td id=d48 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b48" name="b48" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('48');">
 <span id="s48" class="" > 48</span></button> </td>   <td id=d49 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b49" name="b49" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('49');">
 <span id="s49" class="" > 49</span></button> </td>   <td id=d50 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b50" name="b50" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('50');">
 <span id="s50" class="" > 50</span></button> </td> </tr><tr class="d-flex" align="center">  <td id=d51 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b51" name="b51" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('51');">
 <span id="s51" class="" > 51</span></button> </td>   <td id=d52 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b52" name="b52" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('52');">
 <span id="s52" class="" > 52</span></button> </td>   <td id=d53 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b53" name="b53" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('53');">
 <span id="s53" class="" > 53</span></button> </td>   <td id=d54 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b54" name="b54" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('54');">
 <span id="s54" class="" > 54</span></button> </td>   <td id=d55 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b55" name="b55" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('55');">
 <span id="s55" class="" > 55</span></button> </td>   <td id=d56 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b56" name="b56" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('56');">
 <span id="s56" class="" > 56</span></button> </td>   <td id=d57 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b57" name="b57" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('57');">
 <span id="s57" class="" > 57</span></button> </td>   <td id=d58 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b58" name="b58" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('58');">
 <span id="s58" class="" > 58</span></button> </td>   <td id=d59 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b59" name="b59" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('59');">
 <span id="s59" class="" > 59</span></button> </td>   <td id=d60 style="" ><span id="sid"></span>
 <button type="button" disabled style=" color: white;" id="b60" name="b60" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block ms" onclick= "guardarposie('60');">
 <span id="s60" class="" > 60</span></button> </td> </tr>
     
     
     </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Com `table` como vc fez não é possível, pois como `media queries` vc  não consegue criar novas `TRs`, e sem novas `TRs` vc não consegue fazer novas "fileiras" de conteúdos. `Table` não é para criar layout. Então se vc tem 10 `TD` por `TR`, não tem "ajuste" responsivo que vai fazer ficar 5 `TD` por `TR` por exemplo.... CSS não cria tags HTML no DOM... Pense em outra forma de fazer o layout, ou saiba que vc sempre vai ter 10 `TD` por `TR`...

Resumindo vc não consegue partir uma `TR` com `10 TDs` em duas `TRs` de `5 TDs` só com `@media`

Agora se vc quer fazer uma "gambiarra" vc pode ter duas tabelas, um para telas grandes, e uma para telas pequenas, e quando estiver em determinada largura de tela vc mostra uma tabela e esconde a outra, e vise-versa.

Aqui tem um exemplo, abaixo de 800px eu mostro a tabela para celulares.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.mobile {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .mobile {
        display: table;
    }
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="desktop">
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>09</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="mobile">
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>09</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: gostei da sua ideia. E como determinar se estou no celular ou desktop?

Comment: @user2876585 isso aqui vai te dar uma ideia. Mas basicamente não tem muito como saber, vc vai ter que fazer seu CSS para a largura de tela, e não pensando se é mobile ou desktop. A não ser que vc use algum JS para saber se o dispositivo de acesso é um ou outro... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386448/resolu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-m%c3%a1xima-ideal-para-exibir-conte%c3%bado-em-modo-mobile